# why filterOptions not working as expected in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

why list filter is not working as expected ..
I am using material Autocomplete component.

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/69953595-material-ui-5-autocomplete-filtered-options-count-forked-l4n6mw?file=/demo.tsx:804-817

```
import * as React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const _filterOptions = createFilterOptions();

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [optionCount, setOptionCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(top100Films);
  const filterOptions = React.useCallback((options, state) => {
    const results = _filterOptions(options, state);

    if (optionCount !== results.length && results) {
      setOptionCount(results.length);
      //setOptions(results);
    }

    return results;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Typography mb={2}>Option count: {optionCount}</Typography>
      <Autocomplete
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

when I am using "DUMMY"  .. it should show one item but currently showing more then one item why ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that options have duplicated keys, because Autocomplete uses `getOptionLabel` as a key by default.
You can set correct key by using `getOptionKey` like this and it should work as expected.

```
  <Autocomplete
    filterOptions={filterOptions}
    options={options}
    getOptionKey={option => option.service_id}
    sx={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
  />
```